# Connection to Access DB from RStudio stopped working after Microsoft Updates

Tags: r, odbc, rstudio, rodbc

I have `windows 10` and `MS Office 365 Pro Plus` on my machine. They are both 64-bit and I did not have any problem running my `R` Scripts until today that some Microsoft Updates were pushed to our system.

This is how I got connected from inside `R` script to the `Access` database:

```
library(RODBC)
db_address <- "S:/KTP/Inter/Data/Tools/Mend.accdb"
db <- odbcConnectAccess2007(db_address)
```

This is the error I get. I read for hours and tried everything possible, but none seems to work. Anyone has encountered this problem?

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :   [RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code
>   63, message [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error
>   Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process
>   0x3374 Thread 0x2f14 DBC 0xfd96df78
>   Jet'. 2: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :   [RODBC] ERROR: state
>   HY000, code 63, message [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access
>   Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile)
>   Ace DSN for process 0x3374 Thread 0x2f14 DBC 0xfd96df78
>   Jet'. 3: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :   [RODBC] ERROR: state
>   HY000, code -1073, message [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]
>   The database you are trying to open requires a newer version of
>   Microsoft Access. 4: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) : ODBC connection
>   failed